# Google BigQuery - Scheduled Queries 3 Hour Limit

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the new schedule query feature in BigQuery, I wondered if anyone knew why you can only schedule queries every 3 hours?

From the docs I found 
"The shortest allowed period is three hours"
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

I know it's only in beta so hopefully there'll be plans to change it, wondered if anyone knew if there was a reason for the limitation other than it being new.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer as to "why" there was a 3 hour limit.  But at the time of this writing, the 3 Hour Limit has been relaxed and you can now schedule queries to run at sub-hour intervals.  For example you can have a query with a schedule time of "every 15 minutes".

Google BigQuery document has been updated: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries